# Append image to a given cell

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I would like to show a small square in the bottom right instead of showing the text of the event in the cell (=day).

The point is, when there is a small square in the bottom right corner, there is an important date.

My issue is that the image is being appended multiple times when it should be appended just once.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar
({
    theme: true,
        header:
        {
            left: 'prev,next day',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '2014-11-12',
        editable: false,
        eventLimit: false, // allow "more" link when too many events
        dayRender: function(date, element, view)
            {
                $('.fc-today').append('<img src="images/square.png">');
            }
});
```

The result is in FireBug:

```
<td class="fc-day-number fc-fri fc-today ui-state-highlight" data-date="2014-12-19">
19
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
<img src="images/square.png">
```

Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`dayRender`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/dayRender/) assuming it will only be called for the current day (today). This assumption is incorrect.

This callback is executed for each day that is present in the calendar. So, if you want to execute some code for the current day you'll need to have a condition that guarentees that the current `element` is the current day.

Something like this:

```
dayRender: function(date, element, view)
{
    if (element.attr('data-date') == moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')) {
        $('.fc-today').append('<img src="images/square.png">');
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this, but should work. Be aware that if you want to do this in cells (days) that have events, you should probably use [`eventRender`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) or [`eventAfterAllRender`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterAllRender/)

Comment: Thank you! The best solution is to do with eventRender: element.append

Comment: @AndySteen I'm glad you worked it out. Please consider accepting my answer if it was helpful to you.